# strtotime for DD/MM/YYYY not working properly

Tags: php, date, datetime-format

I got this type of date from DB **'10/09/19'** It's today date(10th sept 2019).

```
$date = '10/09/19';
       //DD/MM/YY
$newdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
echo $newdate; //output 2010-09-19
exit;
```

It's giving me 2010-09-19. it means **19th Sept 2010**.

I expect **10-09-2019**(10th Sept 2019). I already tried many solutions from SO but no luck. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong??

Comment: check out `DateTime` ~ specifically `DateTime::createFromFormat `

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.` From the docs. Specifically, **If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.**

Comment: https://3v4l.org/hSBtj

Comment: @Nick Your last fiddle comment worked for me. Thanks for it. Add it in answer I'll select it.

Comment: @DilipHirapara having closed the question as a duplicate no-one can post answers any more. I'm happy enough that you have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` class can be used in situations like this - it has the useful method `createFromFormat`

```
    $date='10/09/19';   //dd/mm/yy
    $new=DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date )->format('Y/m/d');
    echo $new;  //2019/09/10
```

Comment: `$d = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', '10/09/19');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');` this @nick comment worked for me.